# jquery remove a element if not text is after it

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having a real hard time on trying to understand how to remove this element when no text is found after it

example HTML

```
<ul>
   <li>Keep This Text
      <a>Keep This Text</a>
   </li>
   <li>Keep This Text
      <a>Keep This Text</a>
   </li>
   <b class="warning">Comments:</b>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>Keep This Text
      <a>Keep This Text</a>
   </li>
   <li>Keep This Text
      <a>Keep This Text</a>
   </li>
   <b class="warning">Comments:</b>Keep b.warning element if text appears after it
</ul>
```

I would like it to look like this , when no text is found after the the b.warning

```
<ul>
   <li>Keep This Text
      <a>Keep This Text</a>
   </li>
   <li>Keep This Text
      <a>Keep This Text</a>
   </li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li>Keep This Text
      <a>Keep This Text</a>
   </li>
   <li>Keep This Text
      <a>Keep This Text</a>
   </li>
   <b class="warning">Comments:</b>Keep b.warning element if text appears after it
</ul>
```

Comment: Why would you have a `<b>` element as a direct child of a `<ul>` element? That's invalid HTML.

Comment: Not that it matters too much, but your sample of having a `<b>` tag inside a `<ul>` [is not valid html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2).

Comment: It's not my HTML and I don't have authorization to change it directly, the site is well over 15+ years old

Answer (score 2):

Just use this row:

```
if($('b')[0].nextSibling) {
  $('b')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = '';
  $('b.warning').hide();
}
```

And here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cfgr9/532/

Thanks to @nnnnnn and @samuel for their help in comments.

Comment: I'll add the check for existence in few minutes

Comment: @nnnnnn, hm, no, there is no errors, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/cfgr9/528/

Comment: @nnnnnn, oh, yes, you're right. i have updated the answer

Comment: Cool. In the OP's case maybe there always will be a newline character, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: this is fine. Just add this inside the if statement  `$('b.warning').hide();`

Comment: Having just reread the question, I think samuel is correct. The OP is not asking how to remove the text after the `<b>`, they're saying that if there is no text after the `<b>` then the `<b>` element should be removed, so kind of the opposite to what you've done. (They said "remove this class", but they mean "element", not "class", as per the sample output shown.)

Comment: @samuel, i just missed it somewhere, thanks for your addition!

Comment: Sorry guys, i just missed it

Comment: This is removing the b.warning even if text follows it http://jsfiddle.net/cfgr9/538/